# media player play pause in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-xml, android-button, android-progressbar

How can I make the Play and Pause image buttons look as a single image button. I am hereby attaching my code below.  These are the images used. i Renamed play as start.

[image]
[image]

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class AudioView extends Activity{

 MediaPlayer mp;

    Button p,pu,s,b,f,h,v,c,bu;

     ProgressBar myProgressBar;

        Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://player.trackitdown.net/preview/289245/preview_c-90-feat-red-monkey-yo-dj-original-mix-dos-or-die-traxx.mp3");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.audio_main);

        Log.v("Start Of OnCreate","++");
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,uri);


        final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);
        final Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        final Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backward);
        final Button fwd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fwd);
        fwd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.forward);

        p=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        pu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
        pu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //s=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        f=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fwd);

        Log.v("Button Objects","getting man");

        play.setOnClickListener(mListener);
        pause.setOnClickListener(mListener);
        back.setOnClickListener(mListener);
        fwd.setOnClickListener(mListener);


        myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);

        myProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        myProgressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());


        Log.v("End Of OnCreate","--");




    }
    private Runnable myThread = new Runnable(){

          public void run() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           while ( mp.getCurrentPosition()<mp.getDuration()){
            try{
             //myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
                  myProgressBar.setProgress( mp.getCurrentPosition()); 
                //Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Throwable t){
            }
           }
          }

            };


    View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.play:

                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                mp.start();
                p.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pu.setClickable(true);
                p.setClickable(false);
                   //seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
                   new Thread(myThread).start();

                break;
            case R.id.pause:
                mp.pause();
                pu.setClickable(false);
                p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                p.setClickable(true);
                break;

            case R.id.back:
                int dur = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                int pos = (dur>10000 ? dur-5000:0);
                mp.seekTo(pos);
                break;
            case R.id.fwd:
                int curpos = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                int dur2 = mp.getDuration();

                int pos2 = (curpos+5000>dur2 ? dur2: curpos+5000);
                mp.seekTo(pos2);
                break;


            }

        }


    };

   }
```

And the XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <ImageView android:layout_width="176dp"
               android:layout_height="208dp"
               android:src="@drawable/audio_icon"/> 

       <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        />
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/fwd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
    />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Simple, you use the same button and simply replace its resource at runtime to alternate between play & pause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your button to say Play at first. Combine play and pause code into one. Set and check a flag to see if play or pause is pressed and change text accordingly.

So you'll only have one button and two boolean fields:

```
 boolean play=true, pause=false;

    final Button playPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
            playPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);

    playPause.setOnClickListener(mListener);
```

Now, in your listener code, do this:

```
case R.id.play:

            if(play)
            {
                play=false;
                pause=true;

                //change image for button
                playPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);

                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                mp.start();
                p.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pu.setClickable(true);
                p.setClickable(false);
                   //seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
                   new Thread(myThread).start();

                }
            if(pause)
            {
                play=true;
                pause=false;

                 //change image for button
                playPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);

                mp.pause();
                pu.setClickable(false);
                p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                p.setClickable(true);
            }
            break;
```

Change the text on your button accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
if(!mp.isPlaying() || isCompleted) {
  isCompleted = false;
  mp.start();
} else {
  mp.pause();
}
```

add a variant:

```
private boolean isCompleted = true;
```

add listener:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            isCompleted = true;
        }}
    );
```