# get the current state of MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android

I am not much experienced so I copied code from somewhere; but Now I can get the state mediaplayer; All I want to do is to get the current state of mediaplayer and then show pause button when it's playing ; and play button when it's paused/buffering;

I am using shoutcast streaming in it; I want to show pause button or something loading status when it is being loaded initially (buffering); and when it is loaded and started playing the the pause button ; and when for some reason it starts buffering again it should show play button or Loading status on main activity

here is my code;

```
   public class Myradio extends AsyncTask implements OnBufferingUpdateListener {
    private static Context mContext;
    // private static MyProgressDialog pdialog;
    public static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private MediaPlayer mpLoop = new MediaPlayer();

    public Myradio(Context theContext) {
        mContext = theContext;
        mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1) {
                Log.v("Buffring Update", "");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    public static void startRadio(String streamUrl) {
        mp.reset();

        mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error in MediaPlayer: (" + what
                        + ") with extra (" + extra + ")");
                return false;
            }
        });
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(streamUrl);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public static void stopRadio() {

        mp.stop();

    }

    public static void resumeRadio() {

        // mp.();
        // mp.setLooping(false);
        // mpLoop.stop();

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("Buffring Update", "Buffring Update");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this like (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29)):

```
if(MediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
  //show the pause button
}
else{
  //show the play button
}
```

Check this [tut](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/dealing-with-the-android-media-player/) too.

Comment: Something like `mpLoop.isPlaying()`.

Comment: I think it will get the state of mediaplayer everytime it is called; But I want something which will autoupdate the state of mediplayer. I mean something like listeners.

Comment: But you got functions like `startRadio()`, `stopRadio()` and `resumeRadio()`, you can put this inside those functions, since they are only the ones which actually change the state of the `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: I am using shoutcast streaming in it; I want to show pause button or something loading status when it is being loaded initially (buffering); and when it is loaded and started playing the the pause button ; and when for some reason it starts buffering again it should show play button or Loading status on main activity

Comment: Then this is what you're in a need of -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnBufferingUpdateListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener)

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951506/media-player-play-pause-in-android

Comment: Then you'll need to set up a `setOnCompletionListener()` -> Check here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)

Comment: ok; got something working; I am not sure why onBufferingUpdate not working; I implemented onPrepared listener and it worked. Will onCompletionListener be called when media is being buffered?

`mp.setOnPreparedListener(
               new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                   
      
       @Override
       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("Prepared","Prepared");
        
       }
               });`

Comment: From the link I gave above-> Register a callback to be invoked when the end of a media source has been reached during playback.

Comment: how can check loading status of media player for show or not showing ProgressBar?