# Android: How to create media player buttons in xml? (no image)

Tags: android, xml, button, media-player, vector-graphics

I am creating an app that has play stop forward reverse functionality. But I am struggling to find standard media player button images for them. I was wondering if this can be done in xml like vector graphics so that I do not have to cater for different image sizes for different resolution devices. Or is there a better way of achieving this?

Any help will be appreciated

I am looking for something similar to following wpf xaml code that would define media player button images

```
<Ellipse.Fill>
    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="0.865" ScaleY="0.805"/>
                <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="135.194" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                <TranslateTransform X="0.006" Y="0.124"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <GradientStop Color="#009D9D9D" Offset="0.995"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
</Ellipse.Fill>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add a image as a background of that button in xml file, And put the image at drawable folder and call it as:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/playBtn"
    />
```

For more see here: [media player play pause in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951506/media-player-play-pause-in-android)

Fit the images for all screen size by doing this:

xlarge (xhdpi): 640x960
large (hdpi): 480x800
medium (mdpi): 320x480
small (ldpi): 240x320

**Important Point:**

Always use **wrap_content** and **match_parent** to avoid this situation of screen size.

**Learn more from here for this issue:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in question, I am avoiding images due to problem with different resolution displays. Also getting such images is difficult. So I am looking for vector graphics like images that are drawn at runtime rather than pasted from image files.

Comment: Its not a problem while you are dealing with images,you only need to define the images size for all...hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi.By doing this you can fit your images for all screen resolution.

Comment: Is there a way of getting such different size images? I wanted to use stock images that are a part of android if possible. If not getting images from third party is difficult due to copyright, etc. So I thought vector graphics was a better solution.

Comment: See my updated answer for all issue with images, I thinks dealing with images is more better and easy approach then vector graphics in android.